# Difference between git status -s and git status --porcelain?

Tags: git

Pretty self explanatory. I am making a script and have come across both being used and parsed, but their output seems to always be the exact same.

Comment: check `git help status` and see what the difference is.

Comment: Wish I could downvote my own question, didn't know that exists. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1 porcelain format is similar to the short format, but is guaranteed not to change in a backwards-incompatible way between Git versions or based on user configuration.

This makes it ideal for parsing by scripts. The description of the short format above also describes the porcelain format, with a few exceptions:

- The user’s color.status configuration is not respected; color will always be off.
- The user’s status.relativePaths configuration is not respected; paths shown will always be relative to the repository root.

Answer (score 4):

**git status --branch --porcelain** " displays the status of the branch (ahead, behind, gone), and used gettext to translate the string. Use hardcoded strings when **--porcelain** is used, but keep the gettext translation for " **git status --short** " which is essentially the same, but meant to be read by a human

Comment: Interesting. Did not know you could add both flags to `git status`

Answer (score 1):

while `git status --porcelain` is meant to be parsed, `git status -s` is at least more predictable in its output since Git 2.29 (Q4 2020)

"[`git status --short`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d4e7ec4d9e695d95cc7474f59fba8cc38580e29/Documentation/git-status.txt#L28)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---short))</sup> quoted a path with SP (SPACE  ) in it when tracked, but not those that are untracked, ignored or unmerged.
They are all shown quoted consistently.

See [commit 7c37c97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c37c9750a0b402a68c73d0e4644f538a026d121), [commit dfc7f65](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfc7f65c261e923a41c910a11390d487e66eb6fe), [commit a361dd3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a361dd3f798968b3be4bd10d0f4133dc1f48e50b), [commit e2773aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2773aa45f673d26fe425cc5423299726f299f0b), [commit f3fc4a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3fc4a1b8680c114defd98ce6f2429f8946a5dc1), [commit 88910c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88910c9939cee927a3ed1acca8d33a30c90b8fe5), [commit c34d24b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c34d24b8a4d776a0046261b7fc6d0900ea94cc52) (10 Sep 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9d4e7ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d4e7ec4d9e695d95cc7474f59fba8cc38580e29), 18 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`quote_path`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2773aa45f673d26fe425cc5423299726f299f0b): code clarification

> The implementation we moved from wt-status to enclose a pathname that has a SP in it inside a dq-pair is a bit convoluted.
> It lets `quote_c_style_counted()` do its escaping and then
>
> - (1) if the input string got escaped, which is checked by seeing if the result begins with a double-quote, declare that we are done.
>   If there wasn't any SP (SPACE  ) in the input, that is OK, and if there was, the result is quoted already so it is OK, too.
> - (2) if the input string did not get escaped, and the result has SP (SPACE  ) in it, enclose the whole thing in a dq-pair ourselves.
>
> Instead we can scan the path upfront to see if the input has SP (SPACE  ) in it.
> If so, we tell `quote_c_style_counted()` not to enclose its output in a dq-pair, and we add a dq-pair ourselves.
> Whether the input had bytes that `quote_c_style_counted()` uses backslash quoting, this would give us a desired quoted string.
>
> If the input does not have SP in it, we just let `quote_c_style_counted()` do its thing as usual, which would enclose the result in a dq-pair only when needed.

So before Git 2.29:

```
git status -s

M dir1/modified
A  dir2/added
A  "file with spaces"  <===
?? dir1/untracked
?? dir2/modified
?? dir2/untracked
?? file with spaces 2  <==== ?
?? untracked
```

After:

```
git status -s

M dir1/modified
A  dir2/added
A  "file with spaces"   <===
?? dir1/untracked
?? dir2/modified
?? dir2/untracked
?? "file with spaces 2" <==== OK
?? untracked
```